# Test Runner not finding Step Definations and all test are ignored

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber, test-runner

Issue while trying to run cucumber script from Test Runner class.

[It runs from the gherkin file but when the test runner is used the following message is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDjJ1.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: check if run config recognised features https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-cucumber-tests.html#cucumber-run-configuration